# JSON - TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, python-requests

I would like to save market id and identifier from a requests json response:

**json response:**

```
[{u'instrument_id': 16348594, u'instrument_type': u'ESH', u'name': u'Exxon Mobil Corp.', u'instrument_group_type': u'EQ', u'symbol': u'XOM', u'pawn_percentage': 80.0, u'currency': u'USD', u'trada
bles': [{u'lot_size': 1.0, u'market_id': 17, u'display_order': 0, u'tick_size_id': 14560, u'identifier': u'115221'}], u'isin_code': u'US30231G1022', u'multiplier': 1.0}]
```

I am trying do this:

```
    market_id = response['tradables']['market_id']
    identifier_id = response['tradables']['identifier']
```

I am using python 2.7, but am getting this error:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

Comment: `response` is a list, not a dictionary. There is exactly one dictionary in that list.

Comment: That it is a list implies there can be 0 or more than 1 result. What should happen when you have 2 or 5 or 10 of these results?

Comment: Try `response[0]['tradables'][...]` as response is a list with only one element in your example

Comment: I get the same error when I try do that: response[0]['tradeables']

Comment: @SHUMAcupcake: yes, because `response[0]['tradables']` is **also** a list.

Comment: *"json response"* No, that's not JSON.

Comment: In other words, `response[0]['tradables'][0]['identifier']` works, but that assumes there is always going to be one response and one tradable for that one response. You need to work out what should happen for a variable number of responses with a variable number of tradables.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: "but I loaded this from JSON, with the requests library". Yup, it's a Python object and this question has nothing to do anymore with JSON; the parsing stage worked and the OP is not understanding what the resulting datastructure consists of.

Comment: Ok, I should of look what type of object it is first and I should handle number of responses.

Comment: What is the best way to handle it?

Comment: You may want to look at the [`pprint` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html) so you can more readily see what the structure looks like.

Comment: @SHUMAcupcake: we don't know. We don't know what API you are calling or what you want to achieve with the data.